# Delete/extract last character from the string

Tags: string, abap

Of course, question was discussed thousand times ([1](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/696015), [2](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/963412), [3](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1229493)) but nothing was offered except this ugly snippet:

```
data: str type string value 'abcd#',
      len type i.

len = strlen( str ).
len = len - 1.
str = str+0(len).
```

Is there any elegant one-liner to do this? The only prominent way I found so far is

```
SHIFT str RIGHT DELETING TRAILING `,`.
```

However, it requires that you know what the last char is (TRAILING mask) and mask doesn't support regexp or wildcards. Or I am wrong?

This variant doesn't work for me for some reason

```
SHIFT string RIGHT BY 1.
```

Maybe somebody knows more beautiful syntax to do this in one line? Anything new in ABAP 7.40 or 7.50?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SUBSTRING to get the last character of a string:

```
DATA: str TYPE string VALUE 'abcd#'.
str = substring( val = str off = strlen( str ) - 1 len = 1 ).
```

str will be '#'

To remove the last character of a string (like in your example):

```
str = substring( val = str off = 0 len = strlen( str ) - 1 ).
```

Type in SUBSTRING in your ABAP Editor and hit F1 on it, there are some more variations (substring_after, substring_before, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

A trick I've used in the past:

```
DATA l_str TYPE string VALUE `abcd#`.

SHIFT l_str RIGHT by 1 PLACES CIRCULAR. " move last char to start, read it from l_str(1)
l_str = l_str+1. " remove it.
```

Comment: This almost the same variant as the `SHIFT` i proposed, even longer. Though, also an option.

Comment: My solution is one statement less, since you omitted extraction of the last char. Thus this is the most efficient.

Comment: PS: I look at ABAP statement counts since I write optimal code for library components. It's always a trade-off between perceived simplicity and speed.

Comment: The more the number of characters in `l_str` is big, the more `shift` is slow, while `substring` speed doesn't vary.